# Linear regression: Proof

Tags: regression, time-series

Lets suppose that I have the next linear regression:

$$Y= \alpha + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3 + \varepsilon$$

And lets suppose that I train it in 100 days and I obtain the betas that fit accurately the model (the error is mean reverting to zero).

Now, lets suppose that I continue using this betas out of the sample (in the following 40 days).

¿It is true (and how could I demonstrate) that if the model breaks (the error is not mean reverting) , it means that the correlation pairwise between the predictor variables ($X_1, X_2, X_3$) has broken?

Comment: If I understand your question, then I do not see why that would be true. We have $\bar{\varepsilon} = \bar{Y} - \overline{\left(\alpha + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3\right)}  = \bar{Y} - \left(\alpha + \beta_1 \bar{X_1} + \beta_2 \bar{X_2} + \beta_3 \bar{X_3}\right)$. Notice that there are no product terms  $\overline{\left(X_iX_j\right)}$ on the right hand side.

Comment: You're fitting regression to time series data?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I am fitting regression to sime series data.